# How to state unpleasantness in written form? let becomes make

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

In English, unpleasantness can be stated by changing [let to make](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/whats-difference-between-let-and-make).

Classmate sharing pleasant things to classmate:

```
My parents let me eat chocolates.
```

> 我父母**让**我吃巧克力

Classmate complaining to classmate:

```
My parents are making me eat vegetables.
```

> 我父母**让**我吃蔬菜

As both use use **让**, the second example does not sound complaining at all. Or perhaps it sounds complaining, as most kids universally hates vegetables.

Here’s an example where enjoyment/non-enjoyment can’t be inferred:

```
My parents let me eat apples.

My parents are making me eat apples.
```

Both are translated as:

> 我父母**让**我吃苹果

Unpleasantness can be stated verbally using length of tones, sound volume.

However, in written Chinese, what’s the best way to state unpleasantness  in place of the word "making me"? Aside from prefixing the sentence with 哎呀

Answer (score 3, accepted):

让 (to make) implies "to force/ to order". If something has to be forced upon you, that something is most likely unpleasant to you

you can use:

- 强迫/ 迫: "to force" . e.g. 我父母迫我吃苹果 (my parent force me to eat apple/ my parent make me eat apple)
- 硬是要/ 硬要: "to force" . e.g. 我父母硬是要我吃苹果 (my parent force me to eat apple)

> 我父母硬是要[**让**]我吃苹果 (my parent stubbornly/ forcefully [**make**] me eat apple)
>
> 我父母硬是要[**让**]我吃苹果 would not be misinterpreted as "my parent stubbornly/ forcefully [**let**] me eat apple)

Side note: "係都要" is the Cantonese equivalent of "硬是要". e.g. "我父母係都要我食苹果"

Comment: For "My parents is making me eat apple" (the kid don't want apple), my wife (Chinese) said that 逼 is preferable over 迫. But she can’t explain it to me well why it is so  However, she said she prefers 硬是 over 逼. She said she will say it as 我父母硬是要让我吃苹果 instead of 我父母逼我吃苹果