# How to use the 让 character

Tags: vocabulary, word

I don't understand the meaning of **让**. I found out that it could be used to ask permission, but also to permit or authorize. This is really confusing to me because I never know what it means... Could anyone explain to me how to use well, and how to understand it well?

I found these exemples :

> 奥运会可以**让**世界认识中国。
> 妈妈**让**弟弟做作业。
> 上课的时候，老师**不让** 我们 说。

Thank you.

Comment: The functions of 让 depend on context. See  https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35435/is-%e8%ae%a9-more-make-than-let

Comment: https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Causative_verbs

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand now.

Comment: Souldn't the first example be:  奥运会可以让世界认识中国

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general "让" means "Let"

1. "奥运会可以**让**世界**认识**中。" = **Let...known**
2. 妈妈**让**弟弟做作业。 = Let
3. 上课的时候，老师**不让** 我们 说。= Don't let.

The "Let" word in English, we may use it to ask for permission. However in Chinese, not only it can be used to ask for permission, it can also be used to describe a consequence of an act (Made me to).

Eg. 他让我用他的车 = He let me to use his car.

Eg. 他让我觉得尴尬 = He made me feel awkward.